# How can I access and display image stored in storage/app/public?

Tags: php, laravel

I read documentation but to no avail. Path seems correct and I also tried using asset($path). The documentation something about symbolic link and it is a bit confusing to me.
Please help.

Comment: Write please your Laravel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symlink is just a reference about another file/dir (a kind of shortcut, if you are familiar with this on Windows). You just have to run this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It will create a link to your storage path in your public path. Then you can use your link to file in your blade templates just like this:

```
{{ asset('storage/file.txt'); }}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

More about symlink: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link